# C++ global configuration class or source visible to all application?

Tags: c++, config

This is more of c++ prencble app design Question 
say i like to have central configuration class which way should i do it :

1. as class with configuration is set in the constructor and each app object with 
   hold this configuration object reference ( pointer )
2. as simple source file that included in each class that needs this configuration ?

in the configuration file should be enums, structs , primitives types

Comment: Including one source file (not header) from another is rarely appropriate.  That's what the linker is for.

Comment: what do you mean , can you elaborate ?

Comment: Doing something like `#include <config.cpp>` means that every other source file will have a duplicate definition of any variables and functions defined in that file.  This is likely to cause problems at link time.  If you want to have a global variable, *declare* it in a header and `#include` *that* in all your source files, but *define* it only once, in its own source file.

Comment: why should i include cpp file ... ? 
i just want to write global configuration in the right way

Comment: @Wyzard regarding your second option, you can define the global variable in the source file and then use extern to only declare this variable in the header file.

Comment: You *shouldn't* `#include` one `.cpp` file from another.  But that's my interpretation of "a simple source file that included in each class".

Comment: what about singleton , in case i need to load file into memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton is a good option here. For example:

```
class Config
{
    Config() {} //The constructor is private.
    static Config * instance;
    void initialize(); //Creates instance.
public:
    static get()
    {
        if (!instance)
        {
            initialize();
        }
        return instance;
     }
};
```

You need to place this in the header file and include this header to all files, which use the config. You would also need to define a static variable in a single cpp file (as usual C++ static class variable).